# ORDER BY not behaving as expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Good day.**

**First i have query:**

```
   ;
    WITH ranked AS (
      SELECT
        p.id_price as p_id_price, 
        p.id_service as p_id_service, 
        p.name as p_name, 
        p.name_original as p_name_original, 
        p.id_producer_country as p_id_producer_country, 
        p.id_firm as p_id_firm, 
        f.name as f_name, 
        f.address as f_address, 
        f.phone as f_phone, 
        city.name as city_name, 
        pc.name as pc_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY p.id_firm
          ORDER BY
            CASE  -- this criterion puts matching products before non-matching ones
              WHEN p.name like '%test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS
              THEN 1 ELSE 2
            END,
            p.id_price  -- you may use any sorting criteria at this point,
                        -- just ensure it makes the results predictable
        ) AS rnk
      FROM Price p 
      left join Firm f 
        on f.id_service=p.id_service 
        AND f.id_city=p.id_city 
        AND f.id_firm=p.id_firm 
      left join City city 
        on city.id_city = p.id_city 
      left join Producer_country pc 
        on pc.id_producer_country = p.id_producer_country 
      WHERE p.id_city='73041' 
        AND p.include='1' 
        AND p.blocked='0' 
        AND f.blocked='0' 
        AND ( f.name like '%test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS
           OR p.name like '%test%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS )
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM ranked
    WHERE rnk = 1 
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN f_name LIKE '%$..' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
              f_name
        ;
```

**The ORDER BY did not work:**

[image: results]

**[Structure tables here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4802/2)**

**I need to f_name sort in ascending numbers after the $ sign**

Why didn't the `ORDER BY` behave as expected?

Comment: you aliased `f.name as f_name`

Comment: @Gibron thanks but i ask other question(mix up)

Comment: is `'%$..'` actually your like query?  It doesn't match the strings you circled.  Did you mean `'%$%'`?

Comment: me need make analog query on page http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1514/3  on this page orer by work but in my big query - script does not sort f_name in numerical order after $ ascending

Comment: @Gibron I need f_name to sort in ascending numbers after the $ sign

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26797/discussion-between-gibron-and-leo-loki)

Comment: @Gibron query not sort f_name in ascending numbers after the $ sign. results here http://uploads.ru/uN7J5.png

Comment: @Gibron ok come to chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing further, realized that we need to sort the same string in two ways.  First if it has a `$` character at all then second by the string present after a `$` character.  Given that the `ORDER BY` would be:

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN f_name LIKE '%$%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
  SUBSTRING (name ,CHARINDEX('$' , name)+1, (LEN(name)) - CHARINDEX('$', name) ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

`f.name` is only valid on the `WITH` clause. When you want to order the records again, use the *alias* provided,

```
CASE WHEN f_name LIKE '%$..' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: try `'%$.'`, and what is your expected result?

Comment: now result http://i.stack.imgur.com/17BHZ.png
but I need to get the results in the same manner as companies here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d1514/3

Comment: script does not sort f_name in numerical order after $ ascending

Comment: have tried using `%$%`? OR `CASE WHEN f_name  COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS LIKE '%$%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, f_name`

Comment: with `%$%` - http://uploads.ru/uN7J5.png
with `OR CASE WHEN f_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CI_AS LIKE '%$%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, f_name` - http://uploads.ru/Ci70e.png

query not sort f_name in ascending numbers after the $ sign...

Comment: then it requires additional parsing to get their numbers. is there any chance that you can add additional int column in the table and make that controls the order of the records?